# Showing progress whilst running a system() command in Perl

Tags: perl

I have a Perl script which performs some tasks, one of which is to call a `system` command to `"tar -cvf file.tar....."`.

This can often take some time so I'd like the command line to echo back a progress indicator, something like a `#` echoing back to screen whilst the `system` call is in progress.

I've been doing some digging around and stumbled across `fork`. Is this the best way to go?   Is it possible to fork off the `system` command, then create a while loop which checks on the staus of the `$pid` returned by the fork?

I've also seen references to `waitpid`.... I'm guessing I need to use this also.

```
fork system("tar ... ")
while ( forked process is still active) {
    print #
    sleep 1
}
```

Am I barking up the wrong tree?

Many thanks
John

Comment: The return value of `fork` is the child's process ID, if it is the parent, or 0 if it is the child, or undef if the fork failed. See perldoc -f fork.

Answer (score 7):

Perl has a nice construction for this, called "pipe opens." You can read more about it by typing `perldoc -f open` at a shell prompt.

```
# Note the use of a list for passing the command. This avoids
# having to worry about shell quoting and related errors.
open(my $tar, '-|', 'tar', 'zxvf', 'test.tar.gz', '-C', 'wherever') or die ...;
```

Here's a snippet showing an example:

```
  open(my $tar, '-|', 'tar', ...) or die "Could not run tar ... - $!";
  while (<$tar>) {
       print ".";
  }
  print "\n";
  close($tar);
```

Replace the `print "."` with something that prints a hash mark every 10 to 100 lines or so to get a nice gaugebar.

Comment: Hi Johan...that is exactly what i'm after!  Many thanks for your reply and example.  I always find it much easier when seeing example code.
Regards
John

Comment: The comma is not needed, I removed it from the example ;-)

Comment: :-) - Thanks Johan.   One thing....does this method only work on commands which write something to STDOUT?  It seems to work perfectly when using tar zcvf, but there's another command i'm using which does not echo anything back to STDOUT.....when I try and open a pipe to this command, i don't see the print "."  :(

Comment: @john yes, it only works if the command writes something. If the child process doesn't write anything then you need to use a different construction, like `fork`/`exec`/nonblocking `waitpid`/`sleep`.

@Johan your code sample would be better with a `$|++` so that the dots are printed immediately. :)

Answer (score 6):

An example that doesn't depend on the child process writing any kind of output, and just prints a dot about once a second as long as it's running:

```
use POSIX qw(:sys_wait_h);
$|++;

defined(my $pid = fork) or die "Couldn't fork: $!";

if (!$pid) { # Child
  exec('long_running_command', @args) 
    or die "Couldn't exec: $!";
} else { # Parent
  while (! waitpid($pid, WNOHANG)) {
    print ".";
    sleep 1;
  }
  print "\n";
}
```

Although it could probably stand to have more error-checking, and there *might* actually be something better already on CPAN. [Proc::Background](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Proc::Background) seems promising for abstracting this kind of job away but I'm not sure how reliable it is.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your help on this. I will give this a try also and see which method best suits.  I liked your $|++ tip above.  I've been doing a select(STDOUT) and then $|=1

Answer (score 2):

```
$|++;    
open(my $tar, 'tar ... |') or die "Could not run tar ... - $!";
      while ($file=<$tar>) {
           print "$file";
      }
      print "\n";
      close($tar);
```

This prints the filenames received from tar.

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like this

```
open my $tar, "tar -cvf file.tar..... 2>&/dev/null |"
    or die "can't fork: $!";
my $i = 0;
while (<$tar>) {
    if( i++ % 1000 == 0 ) print;
} 
close $tar or die "tar error: $! $?";
```

Comment: Please use local lexicals for your file/process handles, not globals.

Comment: My perl is a little rusty, I didn't know this is possible for filehandles. Thanks, I'll try that next time.

Answer (score 1):

For showing progress during a long-running task, you will find [Term::ProgressBar](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Term::ProgressBar) useful -- it does the "printing of # across the screen" functionality that you describe.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on what Hobbs provided if you would like to get the data from the child process back into the Parent process you need to have an external conduit. I ended up using the tempfs because it was simple like a file, but does not put IO hits on the disk.

** Important ** 
You need to exit the child process, because otherwise the "child" process will continue along the same script and you will get double `print` statements. So in the example below `foreach (@stdoutput)` would happen two times despite only being in the script once.

```
$shm_id = time;  #get unique name for file - example "1452463743"
$shm_file = "/dev/shm/$shm_id.tmp";   #set filename in tempfs
$| = 1;  #suffering from buffering
print ("Activity Indicator: "); #No new line here
defined(my $pid = fork) or die "Couldn't fork: $!";
if (!$pid) { # Child
    @stdoutput=`/usr/home/script.pl -o $parameter`; #get output of external command
    open (SHM, ">$shm_file");
    foreach (@stdoutput) {
        print SHM ("$_");  #populate file in tempfs
    }
    close (SHM);        
    exit;  #quit the child process (will not kill parent script)
} else { # Parent
    while (! waitpid($pid, WNOHANG)) {
    print ("\#");  # prints a progress bar
        sleep 5;
    }
}
print ("\n"); #finish up bar and go to new line
open (SHM, "$shm_file");
    @stdoutput = <SHM>;  #Now open the file and read it. Now array is in parent
close (SHM);
unlink ($shm_file);  #deletes the tempfs file
chomp(@stdoutput);
foreach (@stdoutput) {
    print ("$_\n");  #print results of external script
}
```